# Shiny widget not appearing in sidebarPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am using `shinydashboard::sidebarSearchForm` in a Shiny app and would like to place other widgets below it. However, whenever I do, they are pushed out of the `sidebarPanel` and into the whitespace below the sidebar. In the code the code below, the `materialSwitch` is in `sidebarPanel` but renders *outside* of the sidebar. If you put the `materialSwitch` above the `sidebarSearchForm` in the `sidebarPanel` though, then all the widgets are correctly contained in the sidebar. How do I ensure all these widgets stay in the sidebar? I want the `materialSwitch` to be at the bottom of the sidebar. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    theme = "simplex",
    "App",
    tabPanel("Do something",
             sidebarPanel(
               
               sliderInput("slider", "Select Num:"
                           ,min   = 1
                           ,max   = 10
                           ,sep   = ""
                           ,value = c(1, 10)),
               
               pickerInput(
                 inputId  = "picker",
                 label    = "Select:",
                 selected = "a",
                 choices  = letters,
                 options  = list(
                   `actions-box` = TRUE,
                   size = 10,
                   `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
                 ),
                 multiple = TRUE
               ),

               h5(HTML("<b>Search</b>")),
               sidebarSearchForm(textId   = "searchText", 
                                 buttonId = "searchButton",
                                 label    = "Include These"
               ),
               
               h5(HTML("<b>Additional Options:</b>")),
               materialSwitch(inputId = "add",
                              label   = "Add?:?", 
                              value   = FALSE, 
                              status  = "primary")
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Tab",
                          "text"
                 )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason for this behaviour

The problem arises from the fact that both, `sidebarPanel` as well as `sidebarSearchForm` create a `<form>` tag and [`<form>`tags must not include other `<form>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). In chrome for example such invalid `HTML` is fixed and my guess is that this fixing moves the element out of the sidebar.

BTW: `sidebarSearchForm` is meant to be used in a `dashboardSidebar` (which does not create a `<form>` tag.

---

### Workaround

I am not an HTML expert, so I do not know whether the `sidebarSearchForm` needs to sit in its own `<form>` (nor did I use this element in the past).

Assuming that it is not necessary to have it in an own `<form>`, you can tweak `sidebarSearchForm` like this:

```r
mySidebarSearchForm <- function (textId, buttonId, label = "Search...", icon = shiny::icon("search")) {
   div(class = "sidebar-form", div(class = "input-group", 
        tags$input(id = textId, type = "text", class = "form-control", 
            placeholder = label, style = "margin: 5px;"), 
        span(class = "input-group-btn", tags$button(id = buttonId, 
            type = "button", class = "btn btn-flat action-button", 
            icon))))
}
```

(This is basically a copy of the original `sidebarSearchForm` replacing the `<form>` by `<div>`)

Then the UI renders as it should:

```
ui <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    theme = "simplex",
    "App",
    tabPanel("Do something",
             sidebarPanel(
               mySidebarSearchForm(textId   = "searchText", 
                                 buttonId = "searchButton",
                                 label    = "Include These"
               ),
               actionButton("go", "go")

             ), 
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Tab",
                          "text"
                 )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(...) {})
```

[image]